# how to make keyup() function only on first keyup in the field

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have created a keyup() function the code is here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 1;
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {

        var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (key === 32) {
            wordscount++;
            $('.input1').append('<p>stop touching your keyboard</p>');
            $('<div class="line">Word ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" class="input' + wordscount + '" value="' + wordscount + '" /><a class="remScnt">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++
            return false;
        }
    });
});

<div id="add_words">
    <div class="line">Word 1<input class="input1" type="text" value="1" /></div>
</div>
```

which is working fine but whenever I press spacebar adding new input field. 
the problem is that I wouldn't able to type long words with space(coming a lot of input field)

eg:- when type "my hello world" shows two input field. Actually I need one extra field.

my question is that is there any option `keyup()` function working only on first time in the same field

If you know could you help me please

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: The problem is that when you are typing "hello world", it is possible. But you don't want to append a new input?

Comment: *"the problem is that I wouldn't able to words with space(coming a lot of input field)"* - dyslexia ?

Comment: please a little effort with your English! :) Otherwise it's not easy to be sure of what you precisely want...

Comment: @SimonEdström When I type "my hello world" then there will be two input input field. actually I need only one extra input when i start type in the field.

Comment: @Stefano I have changed a bit on my question. Hope you can understand now. sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you serach for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 1;
$("#add_words").on("keyup","input[type='text']",function(e) { // Set the eventhandler to the inputs

        var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (key === 32) {
            if($(this).attr("data-isused")!="true"){ // Check if THIS textbox have append a new textbox?
            $(this).attr("data-isused","true"); // Mark that this textbox has append a new one
            wordscount++;
            $('.input1').append('<p>stop touching your keyboard</p>');
            $('<div class="line">Word ' + wordscount + '<input type="text"     class="input' + wordscount + '" value="' + wordscount + '" /><a class="remScnt">Remove</a>    </div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        //i++ Ignore this, couse its not declared
        return false;
        }
    }
});
```

});

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pURVS/

Comment: exactly brother @Simon Edström :) . Thanks a lot for your help.
sorry for the misunderstanding my English language

Answer (score 5):

You can use the one method to unbind an event automatically after first time use:

```
$("#foo").one("keyup", function() {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can make use of **[jQuery .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**

```
$('#myinput').one('keyup',function(){
 // do something
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what do you want exactly, but try this...

Use HTML5 `data.*` to know who used that space before.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 1;
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {

        var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (key === 32 && $(e.target).data('added')) {  // <=== Here
            $(e.target).data('added', 'added');        // <===  And Here
            wordscount++;
            $('.input1').append('<p>stop touching your keyboard</p>');
            $('<div class="line">Word ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" class="input' + wordscount + '" value="' + wordscount + '" /><a class="remScnt">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @maanu this is pretty much identical to Simon's answer (but written one hour earlier ;-) ), using the html5 data api. `data('added')` == `attr('data-added')` so `added` is the same as `isused` in Simon's answer!

Answer (score 1):

no but you can add class to target input field and test if it already here, then do nothing

Comment: HTML5 data-* is better then class.

Comment: @smoula22 I'm building a malayalam dictionary. This option giving to add new words to dictionary. when some one type a word then there will be a new text field. but here it shows many text fields because some words have many space :(

Comment: I used `data.*` in my answer,  tough I didn't fully undersatnd what that guy wants.

Answer (score 1):

You should use bind and unbind methods:

http://api.jquery.com/bind/
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

For example:

```
var handler = function() {   
  alert('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'); 
  // unbind handler so the function is not executed again
  $('#foo').unbind('click', handler);
}; 
$('#foo').bind('click', handler);
```

In your handler function, if you no longer want it to be executed (after the first key press), you call the unbind method.