# how to use slideDown() with appendTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I would like to use slideDown() with my appendTo()

here is my present code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 1;
    $("#add_words").on("keyup","input[type='text']",function(e) {
            if($(this).attr("data-isused")!="true"){
            $(this).attr("data-isused","true");
            wordscount++;
            $('<div class="line">Word ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" class="input' + wordscount + '" value="' + wordscount + '" /></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            // i++
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

'

```
<div id="add_words">
    <div class="line">Word 1<input class="input1" type="text" value="1" /></div>
</div>
```

my question is that Is there any possibility to apply `slideDown()` with my code ?

Comment: You have to improve your questions! [Last Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209639/how-to-make-keyup-function-only-on-first-keyup-in-the-field)

Comment: @gdoron I have changed my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the following changes it should work:

```
$('<div class="line" style="display:none">Word ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" class="input' + wordscount + '" value="' + wordscount + '" /></div>').appendTo(scntDiv).slideDown();
```

This makes it initially hidden allowing you to slide it down.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the newly appended element is hidden first:

```
$(element).hide().appendTo(someOtherElement).slideDown();
```

Comment: This is the best answer !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that you want to add the HTML to the DOM with `appendTo` and then use `slideDown` to show the added content, right?

In that case you need to make sure that the content is hidden when you append it to the DOM:

```
var html = '<div class="line">Word ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" class="input' + wordscount + '" value="' + wordscount + '" /></div>';
$(html).hide().appendTo(scntDiv).slideDown();
```

**Note** Took the liberty to break all your HTML out into a variable for the sake of readability